# pgfplots does not render the plot properly --- strange line pattern appearing

Tags: pgfplots, plot, contour

When I run the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar,
    colorbar style={
        ytick={-1,0,1},
        yticklabels={$-1$, $0$, $1$},},
    ylabel = $y$,
    xlabel = $x$,
    domain = 0:20,
    y domain = 0:20,
    view = {0}{90},
    point meta min=-1,
    point meta max=1,
    ymax=20,
    ]

    \addplot3[
        surf,shader=interp,
        samples=50,
        domain = 0:20,
        y domain = 0:20 ]
        {cos(deg(y-x))/(x)};

\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the strange output:

[image]

How do I smooth out the strange pattern of lines that's appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a singularity at `x=0` because you divide by `x`. One way to avoid the problem is to adjust the domain to avoid the problematic points.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar,
    colorbar style={
        ytick={-1,0,1},
        yticklabels={$-1$, $0$, $1$},},
    ylabel = $y$,
    xlabel = $x$,
    domain = 0:20,
    y domain = 0:20,
    view = {0}{90},
    point meta min=-1,
    point meta max=1,
    ymax=20,
    ]

    \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,
        samples=50,
        domain = 0.001:20,
        y domain = 0:20 ]
        {cos(deg(y-x))/(x)};

\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can also "cure" the function. The output is virtually the same, but this also works if the domain extends to negative `x`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar,
    colorbar style={
        ytick={-1,0,1},
        yticklabels={$-1$, $0$, $1$},},
    ylabel = $y$,
    xlabel = $x$,
    domain = 0:20,
    y domain = 0:20,
    view = {0}{90},
    point meta min=-1,
    point meta max=1,
    ymax=20,
    ]

    \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,
        samples=50,
        domain = 0:20,
        y domain = 0:20 ]
        {x==0?sign(cos(deg(y))):cos(deg(y-x))/(x)};

\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain what ``{x==0?sign(cos(deg(y))):cos(deg(y-x))/(x)}`` means here? I don't understand

Comment: @QuantumEyedea If `x` equals zero, it evaluates to `sign(cos(deg(y)))`, and to `cos(deg(y-x))/(x)` otherwise.